# What can I do about non-rotated images on a digital picture frame?

Tags: display, rotation, image-orientation

I have taken pictures from digital cameras and scanned old photos, and edited them with Windows 8 photo.  When I try to display the pictures on a digital picture frame, many are rotated incorrectly.  Phillips says I must wash them thru paint one at a time to fix this.  Are there frames that can read them like the computer does?

Comment: Don't have an answer about which digital frames, but if you do decide to re-orient your files instead, there are better tools than paint, many of which can losslessly auto-rotate a whole batch. The standard is probably [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/), but there's a list of other possibly useful software [here](http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html).

Comment: Windows itself can losslessly rotate images in its image viewer, that's a pretty quick way to do it.

Though a better photo frame should be able to read orientation information and rotate automatically.  Sorry but I don't know specifically which frames do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to know for sure whether a digital picture frame will automatically rotate images for you is to try it. To avoid problems, you can rotate your images prior to copying them to the frame for display.

- **`exiftran`** can losslessly rotate images based on the Exif orientation tag:

  ```
  exiftran -abip *.jpg
  ```
- **[`jhead`](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/)** also uses the Exif orientation tag:

  ```
  jhead -autorot *.jpg
  ```
- To my knowledge, **[`jpegtran`](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/)** does *not* use the orientation tag:

  ```
  jpegtran -copy all -rotate 90 -outfile output.jpg input.jpg
  ```

  However, it does come with a utility `exifautotran` that reads the orientation tag and calls `jpegtran` to perform the actual rotation.

*Keep backups of the originals. Some tools have been known to corrupt the MakerNotes tags when rotating images.*